# MySQL: Select all duplicate MIN from counted group

Tags: mysql

I have this example data and I wanted to query the employee having the lowest count of attendance.

| employee_id | employee | today | time_in | time_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JUAN | 2022-03-04 | 07:23:43 | 05:23:11 |
| 1 | JUAN | 2022-03-03 | 07:05:43 | 05:06:21 |
| 1 | JUAN | 2022-03-02 | 07:12:01 | 05:32:21 |
| 2 | BEN | 2022-03-04 | 07:17:01 | 05:36:21 |
| 3 | WENDY | 2022-03-04 | 07:23:43 | 05:23:11 |
| 3 | WENDY | 2022-03-03 | 07:05:43 | 05:06:21 |
| 3 | WENDY | 2022-03-02 | 07:12:01 | 05:32:21 |
| 4 | JOHN | 2022-03-02 | 07:54:01 | 05:02:42 |

I am able to get the total of how many times their attendance is for a given date range:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) in_count, employee_id, employee
FROM active_attendance
WHERE (today BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY in_count ASC
```

And this yields to:

| in_count | employee_id | employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | BEN |
| 1 | 4 | JOHN |
| 3 | 1 | JUAN |
| 3 | 3 | WENDY |

Now I'm struggling how I would filter only the LOWEST `in_count` in this scenario I want only `BEN & JOHN` to be returned.

How I want it to be:

| in_count | employee_id | employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | BEN |
| 1 | 4 | JOHN |

What I've tried: This only returns the first MIN value and not including the duplicate

```
SELECT MIN(att), employee_id, employee 
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) in_count, employee, employee_id
    FROM 202_active_attendance
    WHERE  today BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-30'
    GROUP BY employee_id
    ORDER BY in_count
) AS test
```

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina It is MySQL version 8.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) in_count, employee_id, employee,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*)) rnk
    FROM active_attendance
    WHERE today BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW()
    GROUP BY employee_id
)

SELECT in_count, employee_id, employee
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Very helpful. But what if the lowest is not 1? How could you make ```rnk``` dynamic?

Comment: @JuliusGuevarra It is already "dynamic," and `RANK()` will assign a rank of 1 to the employee groups having the lowest count, even if that count be something other than one.